# Setting color in an iPad painting app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, colors, paint

I was wondering if anyone could help me implement color selection in my iOS app. Right now, the painting line is only black, but I'd like the user to be able to change the color. Right now I have 5 buttons for 5 different color options. I then tagged each button 1-5, and connected them all to a single `IBAction`. I was thinking I could have an if statement to say if the button is tagged 1, then set color to 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 (red) and so on for each color.
 So, here are the if statements I have:

```
NSString *color = @"0.15, 1.15, 0.15, .8";

-(IBAction)color:(id)sender{

    if ([sender tag] ==1) {
        color = @"0.15, 1.15, 0.15, .8";
    }
    if ([sender tag] ==2) {
        color = @"0.15, 1.15, 0.15, .8";
    }
    if ([sender tag] ==3) {
        color = @"0.15, 1.15, 0.15, .8);";
    }
    if ([sender tag] ==4) {
        color = @"(0.15, 1.15, 0.15, .8";
    }
    if ([sender tag] ==5) {
        color = @"0.15, 1.15, 0.15, .8";
    }
}
```

So, now that I put the variable color in

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color );
```

But, I'm getting the error "Too few arguments to function call, expected 5, have 2"

Thanks for your help!

-Karl

Comment: first, you shouldn't declare the variable 5 times. Put 'NSString *color;' above the if statement, and then say just 'color = @"whatever color you want";' inside the if-statement.

Comment: Thanks so much! That helped a lot. It seems so obbious now,I guess it's been awhile since I've programmed. LOL

Comment: I think I don't have to say you should google 'scope', but that makes things comprehensible for other people with the same problem.

Comment: And is it solved now? If yes, I will post an answer so you can accept that.

Comment: Also, any reason you are using NSString instead of UIColor?

Comment: I thought it would be easier and because thats just the way I made it. Is UIColor better in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help, but I figured out the last part on my own. 
If anyone's interested, this is the code I came up with:

```
double C1 = 1.15;
double C2 = 0.15;
double C3 = 0.15;
double C4 = .8;

'NSString *color = @"0.15, 1.15, 0.15, .8";

-(IBAction)colors:(id)sender{

if (([sender tag] ==1)) {
    C1=  0.15;
    C2 = 0.15;
    C3 = 0.15;
    C4 = .8;
}

else if (([sender tag] ==2)) {

    C1 = 0.15;
    C2 = 1.15;
    C3 = 0.15;
    C4 = .8;
}

else if (([sender tag] ==3)) {
    color = @"1.15, 0.15, 0.15, .8";
    C1 = 1.15;
    C2 = 0.15;
    C3 = 0.15;
    C4 = .8;
}

else if (([sender tag] ==4)) {
    C1 = 0.15;
    C2 = 0.15;
    C3 = 1.15;
    C4 = .8;
}
else if (([sender tag] ==5)) {
    C1 = 1.15;
    C2 = 1.15;
    C3 = 0.15;
    C4 = .8;
}

}

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), C1, C2, C3, C4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
[colorArray addObject:@"0.0,0.0,0.0"];      
[colorArray addObject:@"148.0,0.0,211.0"];  
[colorArray addObject:@"0.0,191.0,255.0"];  
...
*/

-(IBAction)actionColorButton:(id)sender
{
[self setPenColor:[colorArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag] - 1]];
}
```

---

```
-(void)setPenColor:(NSString*)color
{
NSArray *arr = [color componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

colorRed = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] / 255.0;
colorGreen = [[arr objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] / 255.0;
colorBlue = [[arr objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] / 255.0;
...
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 
                           colorRed,
                           colorGreen,
                           colorBlue,
                           1.0);
...
}
```